# Get union of values in for object

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to write the types for a function that accepts records of any structure and transforms the values into a discriminated union. So something like the following:

```
const getKeys = <T extends {key: string}>(items: T[]): T['key'] => {
    // ...
}

// keys should have type "foo" | "bar"
// instead has type string
const keys = getKeys([{ key: "foo" }, { key: "bar" }])

// keys2 should have type "baz" | "qux"
// instead has type string
const keys2 = getKeys([{ key: "foo" }, { key: "qux" }])
```

However, `keys` and `keys2` instead has the type of `string`.

Ideally, you would get the kind of nice API like the following, working example but using records:

```
const getKeys = <T extends string>(items: T[]): T => {
    // ...
}

// keys has type "foo" | "bar"
const keys = getKeys(["foo", "bar"])

// keys2 has type "baz" | "qux"
const keys2 = getKeys(["baz", "qux"])
```

How can I do this?

### Requirements

- Cannot use `as const` on the argument

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/Wyxz2m) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yep! Feel free to write up an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The alternative to [const assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) would be [const type parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-5-0.html#const-type-parameters) introduced in Typescript 5.0.

Previously, typescript would infer a more generic type for the objects; however, `const type assertions` tells the compiler to take the exact type without making it more general.

Implementation:

```
const getKeys = <const T extends { key: string }>(items: T[]): T['key'] => {
  return {} as any
};

// keys should have type "foo" | "bar"
const keys = getKeys([{ key: 'foo' }, { key: 'bar' }]);

// keys2 "baz" | "qux"
const keys2 = getKeys([{ key: 'bar' }, { key: 'qux' }]);
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/MYewdgzgLgBA5gUygaQQTwjAvDAPKSWAFRgQA8oEwATTAbxgGt0AuGaAJwEsw4YBfAHwAKLpQC2ENkQDaAXQCU0mQHJmaFXOyCYdAFAwYHJAFcOYXfxgBDTNbBo9-ANx69AendN0mCAAsQEwAbahg-awA3BBgoNAAHaIAiADMQEESYAB8YRIAjaw5EvQJobwxseCRUDGEZBnU2FVSQFQEAGl0yxvyOVv5FVw8vdQgAJhz8gC8M7MSARxMyIpLYEfGcRBQfWvrWGBUevo7dtEaFsj6BvSA)